# Swift observer before view loaded

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWReveal to create a swipe out menu.

When the app loads it displays a home page which has buttons to other pages in the app. Once the button is pressed the a segue is performed & the menu is updated hi-lighting the newly selected page so that the next time the menu is pulled out it indicated the page the user is currently on.

I am using an observer to update the menu as below. The code works fine once the swipe menu has been loaded then a button is pressed.

However it's not working when the home page is first loaded as the swipe menu observers havn't been created yet.

My question: Is there a way of initialising the swipe menu once the home page has been loaded so that the observer is created? or is there a way of approaching this which I am not seeing?

swipeMenu.swift (Receiving Notification) :

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.changeGiveaway(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("changeGiveaway"), object: nil)

}

func changeGiveaway(notification: Notification){

     print("Change giveway was called")

    homeShadow.isHidden = true
    yanaLiveVideoShadow.isHidden = true
    yanaChatShadow.isHidden = true
    yanaShopShadow.isHidden = true
    yanaProfileShadow.isHidden = true
    horoscopesShadow.isHidden = true
    fortuneTellerShadow.isHidden = true
    dailyGiveAwayShadow.isHidden = false



}
```

home.swift (Post Notification):

```
@IBAction func dailyGiveAway(_ sender: Any) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("changeGiveaway"), object: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "giveAway", sender: self)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here is probably the use of Delegate.

You can create :

```
protocol GiveAwayDelegate: class {
     func changeGiveAway()
}

var delegate: GiveAwayDelegate?

@IBAction func dailyGiveAway(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.changeGiveAway()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController {
            destination.delegate = self
        }
}
```

And Finally in your ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GiveAwayDelegate {

    func changeGiveaway(notification: Notification){

         print("Change giveway was called")

         ...

     }
}
```